# Wrong notification on phone reboot? It has the time right of the latest notification but the text is the first result in database

Tags: java, android, background-service

I have a broadcast receiver. In which I'm trying to reset the alarms after reboot. I used IntentServices to setAlarms and create notifications. I'm using cursor to retrieve values of alarm timings and description and resetting it in onReceive in Broadcast receiver. I have to use loops to reset all alarms. But IntentService sets the alarm but shows wrong notification. I checked logs it has wrong data. I'll post the code. Please advise.  Images are below. [Stack Trace 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6ox.png)[Stack trace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1wl0.png)
    [Notification on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU1Gx.jpg)

BroadCastReceiver class

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String TAG=BroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(Receiver.class.getSimpleName(),"Boot Completed");
           Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(DatabaseContract.content_URI,null,null,null,null);
            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do{

                    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.columns._ID,cursor.getInt(0));
                    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.columns.description,cursor.getString(1));
                    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.columns.isCompleted,cursor.getInt(2));
                    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.columns.priority,cursor.getInt(3));
                    contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.columns.date,cursor.getLong(4));

                   Log.i(Receiver.class.getSimpleName(),"Content Values: "+contentValues.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description));

                    AlarmScheduler alarmScheduler=new AlarmScheduler();
                    alarmScheduler.createAlarm(context,contentValues);
                    contentValues.clear();



                }while ( cursor.moveToNext());
               // AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Log.i(TAG,"Alarm reset after boot:" );
                cursor.close();




            }

           /* Intent intent1=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);*/

    }
}
```

AlarmScheduler Class

```
public class AlarmScheduler {
    public static String TAG="Scheduler";//AlarmScheduler.class.getSimpleName();

  public  void createAlarm(Context mContext, ContentValues contentValues){

       AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);

      //NotificationManager manager=mContext.get

      PendingIntent pendingIntent=ReminderAlarmService.getReminderPendingIntent(mContext,contentValues);
      Log.i(TAG,"Description: "+contentValues.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description)+" | Date: "+contentValues.getAsLong(DatabaseContract.columns.date));
      alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,contentValues.getAsLong(DatabaseContract.columns.date),pendingIntent);
      Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(contentValues.getAsLong(DatabaseContract.columns.date));
      Log.i(AlarmScheduler.class.getSimpleName(),"Alarm set at"+ calendar.getTime());

  }
}
```

IntentServiceClass

```
[public class ReminderAlarmService extends IntentService {


    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public static String TAG="Intent Service";//ReminderAlarmService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static String CONTENTVALUES="ContentValues";
    int notificationId=001;
    public ReminderAlarmService() {
        super(TAG);

    }



    static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, ContentValues contentValues){
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(CONTENTVALUES,contentValues);
        Log.i(TAG,"Description: "+contentValues.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,0);
        //
        context.startService(intent);

        return pendingIntent;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"Destroying");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {


        Intent intent1=new Intent(ReminderAlarmService.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2=PendingIntent.getActivity(ReminderAlarmService.this,0,intent1,0);
        ContentValues contentValues2=intent.getParcelableExtra(CONTENTVALUES);
       // notificationId=contentValues2.getAsInteger(DatabaseContract.columns._ID);
        Log.i(TAG,"Description: "+contentValues2.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description)+" | Date: "+contentValues2.getAsLong(DatabaseContract.columns.date));
//        Log.i(TAG,"Description: "+contentValues2.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description));
        NotificationCompat.Builder  builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(ReminderAlarmService.this,"none").setSmallIcon(android.support.v4.R.drawable.notification_icon_background).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Task Update").setContentText(contentValues2.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description)).setContentIntent(pendingIntent2);
        NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(notificationId,builder.build());


    }

}][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Below is the change I made. Its in IntentService class. Added a flag into PendingIntent. PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT.

```
static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, ContentValues contentValues){
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(CONTENTVALUES,contentValues);
        Log.i(TAG,"Description: "+contentValues.getAsString(DatabaseContract.columns.description));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //
        //context.startService(intent);

        return pendingIntent;

    }
```